# Search queries not showing in custom dashboard in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

The 'search queries' triggering the searches in Google search is not showing in the widget under the custom dashboard in Google Analytics even though these queries are showing up in the search queries report, under acquisition. The property is verified in the search console which is why it does show up in the search queries report under the 'acquisition' column. However, when I try creating a widget for this report in the custom dashboard it is not reflecting these queries there.

While choosing the widget, I have selected a 'Table' and dimension is search query and metric is clicks or impressions.

Answer (score 0):

The widget ***Search Query > Impressions and Metrics*** you are applying, refers to Adwords paid search activity only. 
I don't think you can pull a similar widget report for Organic search (Search console data)